# System.InvalidOperationException: 'A method was called at an unexpected time. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000000E)'

Tags: c#, uwp, wifi-direct

Getting below error,

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'A method was called at an unexpected time. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000000E)'

for below code,

```
        ...
        for (int retry = 0; retry <= retryCount; retry++)
        {
            if (await RequestPairDeviceAsync(_targetDeviceInformation.Pairing)) // excetion happend here
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        ...

    private static async Task<bool> RequestPairDeviceAsync(DeviceInformationPairing pairing)
    {
        DeviceInformationCustomPairing customPairing = pairing.Custom;
        customPairing.PairingRequested += OnPairingRequested;

        PairingRequested.Invoke(_targetDeviceInformation, customPairing);

        DevicePairingResult result = await customPairing.PairAsync(DevicePairingKinds.ConfirmOnly);

        if ((result.Status == DevicePairingResultStatus.Paired) || (result.Status == DevicePairingResultStatus.AlreadyPaired)){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**How to resolve it?**

Comment: Is this pairing functionality a third-party library? Which line is the exception occurring on?

Comment: @TimothyStepanski 3rd line as commented `if (await RequestPairDeviceAsync(_targetDeviceInformation.Pairing))`. No 3rd party libs its a native API

Comment: Could you please add break point to RequestPairDeviceAsync method and tell me which line of code within RequestPairDeviceAsync method throw the exception?

Comment: @YanGu the exception is happened while calling the method even before entering into it.

Comment: Could you please tell me the value of retry when the exception is thrown? I want to know if the exception is thrown at the first time calling the `RequestPairDeviceAsync` method.

Comment: I assure you that the exception happens in the second try. @YanGu-MSFT

Comment: I have tried to reproduced the `System.InvalidOperationException` in my side. Because I don’t know what is `PairingRequested`, I comment the statement  `PairingRequested.Invoke(_targetDeviceInformation, customPairing);`. Without the `PairingRequested` statement, I didn’t reproduce the exception. Could you please tell me what is `PairingRequested`? It is better if you could provide us a sample by using OneDrive or GitHub for testing.